# PUT method is not working in express with prisma

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, prisma

I am using Express, Prisma and PostgreSQL for my project. GET, POST and DELETE methods are working but when I try to use patch method it shows `+ data: ArtistUpdateInput | ArtistUncheckedUpdateInput` `Argument data is missing.`
I tried passing `Name, Link, GenreName` with values. `createdAt and updatedAt` values are auto generated, I don't have to pass them explicitly. Any ideas why I am getting this error?

```js
// Prisma Schema
model Artist {
  id        Int      @default(autoincrement()) @id
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  Name     String
  Link String
  GenreName String
}

// ExpreeJS API
app.put(`/artist/:id`, async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    
    const updatedArtist = await prisma.artist.update({
      where: {
        id: Number(id)
      }
    });

    res.json(updatedArtist);
});
```

Comment: In the example above, you have not passed `data` to `update`. `data` is required to be passed in `update`.

Comment: Oh man my bad thanks for the  help.